# Open TCP port in Windows 7 and read incoming data, what program to use?

Tags: windows-7, networking, port, tcp

I have an external device which can connect over GPRS to the Internet using a SIM card and I want to see what data it sends. I can program it to use my computer as a server and then use a program to read what it sends. The problem is that I don't know what program to use to read the incoming data. Any ideas?

Device on the Internet > My home router > Port forwarding > My computer
I tried Windows 7 Telnet Server but I can't read what is coming.

Comment: Wireshark may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the most common tool for inspecting network traffic. It would also allow [filtering data](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters) from a specific port.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it connects to a particular port (or you can tell it to),
`netcat` might be the simplest way to capture the data going to that port, and none other.

> `nc -l -p`*port_number*  `>`*output_file_name*

The `-l` option puts `netcat` into **l**isten (i.e., server) mode;
without it; `netcat` acts much like telnet client.

Resources:

- [NetCat Tutorial](http://www.packetsource.com/article/security-tools/40061/netcat-tutorial)
- [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat)

Note: On some versions of `netcat`, `-l` implies `-p`, so you should say just `-l` and then the port number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437) (a free utility from Microsoft from their takeover of Sysinternals). It's a GUI-based interface so you should get up and running relatively quickly.